# How do I debug a webhook POST?

Tags: php, post, webhooks

A webhook is sending me a POST, and I want to do some debugging on it.  Currently I'm looping over the array and then sending a mail() to myself instead of printing (because how could I see what's printed to the page?), but I'm betting there's a more efficient way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 2 steps: trigger webhooks and then inspect them. More details on [this blog post](http://blog.superfeedr.com/debugging-webhooks/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://requestbin.com/ lets you create a temporary URL that will show you all the HTTP request data sent to it.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options for debugging:

1. Use a debugger with an IDE, like netbeans. This will run the application and figure out where things are going wrong.
2. Use logfiles of your server, or generated by application exceptions
3. Collect your debug information with a buffer and put it in a file in your public directory. Overwrite with every new request.

Answer (score 2):

http://httpresponder.com/ works also, and lets you configure a canned response if you need one.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite an old question but if you want to see what kind of responses you are going to get from webhooks or you need to need to access the developer environment then there are a selection of tools that can help you.

RequestBin is probably one of the simplest to use by, providing a  unique URL that you can then set this as your endpoint for Event notifications.  Using this URL you can check to see what responses you are receiving.

You can generate a unique URL by creating a **RequestBin**.

An Example URL is this:

http://requestb.in/XXXXXXXX

This will be used to receive **Event Notification Data** and **Receive Inbound Parse Data**.

The results will then be found by heading to your **RequestBin unique URL**.

**Ngork** is also a tool that is useful for creating a local tunnel to your machine.  This makes testing webhooks locally easy.

To setup install and enter the following in your CLI (after signing up first):

```
 $ ngork 3000
```

This would open a connection to the port 3000 that is on your local machine, then at a URL you can put your URL for your PARSE Webhook or Event Webhook.

```
 $ ngrok -subdomain=myappname 3000
```

**Runscope** is a tool for debugging APIs. It acts as a proxy, collecting all data sent to it and passes it on to another point. You may then, later, review what was sent to the API you’re debugging.

Source : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/debug.html

Comment: Plus 1 for ngrok! It's awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://webhook-test.com that gives you an unique URL instantly without any signup/login. You can customize the response content and code as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.reliablewebhook.com/. They also have [a plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ReliableWebhook.ReliableWebhook) for Visual Studio Code for local debugging.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).